# Looping through an array with pass by reference to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, setinterval, pass-by-value

I'm trying to loop through a specified string which has been split into individual characters and then read them back ticker-tape style. I have a function inside a setInterval which is supposed to increment a word counter but I am having difficulty in getting this to work as I can't sent the counter (an integer) into the function by reference. I've read the various pages on this site and others about pass by value vs. pass by reference and I still can't get it to work. Can anyone help? My latest incarnation is below - and it doesn't work :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="demo"></span>

<script>
myFunction();

function myFunction() 
{
    var str = "How are you/doing today?";
    var res = str.split("");  // we now have an array of individual letters
     //  The "/" is intended to be a line break

    var counter = { value: 0 };  // keeps track of where we are

    myvar = setInterval( appendText, 250, res, counter );  // Run every 250ms
    if( counter.value > res.length ) clearInterval(myVar);  // when we read the end of the character array, stop the read out.
}

function appendText( res, c )
{
    var addtext;
    if ( res[c.value] =="/" )
    {
        addtext="<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        addtext = res[c.value];
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=addtext;
    c.value++;   // c is a counter that keeps track of where we are in the text string
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `c` is an object, then what is`res[c]` supposed to access? did you mean to write `res[c.value]`?

Comment: You're comparing `counter` against `res.length` instead of `counter.value` as well.

Comment: Ah, thanks for these comments, I've adjusted the code accordingly and it works better, even though I now have the output going past the end of the character array, oh dear!

Comment: That problem is (most likely) cause by the fact that the check `if( counter.value > res.length ) clearInterval(myVar);` is only performed once, when the page loads and `myFunction()` is executed. Instead you probably want to perform this check after each execution of `appendText`

Comment: `myvar` and `myVar` are also different variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Following comments by @UnholySheep and @user3713422, and including declaration of `myvar` outside scope of `myFunction`, removing reference to undefined  `myVar`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <span id="demo"></span>

  <script>
    myFunction();
    var myvar;

    function myFunction() {
      var str = "How are you/doing today?";
      var res = str.split(""); // we now have an array of individual letters
      //  The "/" is intended to be a line break

      var counter = {
        value: 0
      }; // keeps track of where we are

      myvar = setInterval(appendText, 250, res, counter); // Run every 250ms

    }

    function appendText(res, c) {
      var addtext;

      if (res[c.value] == "/") {
        addtext = "<br/>";
      } else {
        addtext = res[c.value];
      }

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += addtext;
      c.value++; // c is a counter that keeps track of where we are in the text string
      // when we read the end of the character array, stop the read out.
      console.log(c.value, res.length);
      if (c.value === res.length) clearInterval(myvar);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string directly, becaus it has a lenght property, too. And a character is easily accessible with an index.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var res = "How are you/doing today?",
        counter = { value: 0 };

    myInterval = setInterval(appendText, 250, res, counter);
}

function appendText(res, c) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += res[c.value] == "/" ? "<br/>" : res[c.value];
    c.value++;
    if (c.value === res.length) clearInterval(myInterval);
}

var myVar;
myFunction();
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```